# Beautiful Soup & GSpread appending data to Google Sheet, instead of replacing

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup, gspread

Got my first price checker going that monitors 50 products and pulls data, this runs at 3am every day. At the moment the products checked are appending to the existing data which is obviously producing duplicates so over a few days I will end up with 50, 100, 150 rows...

How can I get the Python script to replace or clear the existing data, so the spreadsheet will only ever have 50 products in it?

Here is the top part of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


import json
import gspread
#from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from json import load
import urllib2

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

product_details = []



def connect_to_spreadsheet():
    json_key = json.load(open('0b6bb6f4e5.json'))
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'].encode(), scope)
    #credentials = AssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'].encode(), scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    wks = gc.open("TestSheet")

    worksheet = wks.worksheet('automated')
    last_row = worksheet.row_count 
    last_col = worksheet.col_count - 1 

    for each_row_data in product_details:
        try:
            worksheet.append_row(each_row_data)
        except:
            print "Could not add row data", each_row_data
```

Comment: Found a clear() in the Gspread docs but not sure how to implement in the above code https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Worksheet.clear

Comment: and some clear() in this https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/tests/test.py

Answer (score 0):

The clear() clears the sheet, but the generated content starts after where it was cleared

```
worksheet = wks.worksheet('automated')
worksheet.clear()
```

But clear is the function() required, just need data to start in A2